# GeoServer: serve series of GeoTIFF files in YYYY/MM/DD/ structure

Tags: geoserver, wms, geotiff-tiff

I have a growing archive of satellite data in GeoTIFF format that is stored on disk in a YYYY/MM/DD/ directory format. Each day, the most recent data is added to this archive.
I've spent the last few weeks familiarizing myself with GeoServer and know how to add a single file to a store, and visualize the data through a WMS connection. But know I am ready for the next step and point GeoServer to my data archive.
How could I serve such an archive with GeoServer and set up a WMS service for it?

Comment: Use image mosaic https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/index.html. About WMS time read https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/time.html and for example https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/educational/en/multidim/mosaic_config/temperature_mosaic.html and search more from the web.

Comment: Thank you, user30184, that indeed seems the way forward. I overlooked the fact that ImageMosaic can also deal with time.